# how to debug log4j on a 3rd party jar (code not available)?

Tags: java, log4j

I use a third party software.
The vendor says that they use log4j to log messages.

I configure my log4j.properties and I can see info from my app but never from theirs.

For example,I change the root category to INFO or to ERROR or to DEBUG.

The question is how do I debug this ?

I have got complete control of the source code but not their jar ?

Any suggestion...

Particularly is there a runtime call I can make to the JVM to tell me why it's not logging their packages ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line to your command line :
-Dlog4j.debug=true.

It will show in the system out, how the log4j is initialized.

Comment: probably your log4j is overwrting theirs. you may want to include its log4j configuration in your log4j.properties.

Comment: log4j.xml / log4j.properties / log4j.groovy takes precedence if you've placed any one of these in your classpath directly (WEB-INF/classes). As richardtz mentioned you're log4j would have overwritten the log4j configuration file inside the jar. Do copy relevant logging information from the 3rd party jar into your log4j.properties to have the problem solved.